# Size View to Fit Scene Processing:

Tags: opengl, processing

I am looking for a way, in Processing, to automatically zoom in/out to fit a model which I am creating.

That is, set the view such that there is no part of my object which extends outside of the view of the window.

I've looked through the [reference](http://processing.org/reference/), but haven't seen anything which would aid in this.

I figure I could implement a way to do this, but if there's already a way to do this in Processing easily, I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Note: Also tagged with OpenGL, since the methods used in OpenGL would translate easily to Processing.

Comment: I haven't used Processing, but just by looking at the reference you provided, it seems that using `camera()` with no parameters will do what you want. If you want more control than that, you want the distance between the camera and the object to be greater than (height/2.0) / tan(PI*60.0 / 360.0) where 60.0 is half of the field of view.

Comment: `camera()` without parameters does not appear to work. If I create a sphere (just as an example) with radius `2*height`, where `height` is the height of the window in pixels, I want the whole sphere to show. With `camera()`, this does not happen.

Comment: However, your comment about the camera distance from the object is very helpful. I should easily be able to find this distance and ensure the camera is always farther away from the object than this distance. Thank you.

Comment: I pulled the formula for the camera distance from the `camera()` method, but it should work in general. 'height' should be the height of the bounding box of the object, but it will fail if you have a wide object that is not very tall. In that case you want to use the width of the bounding box instead.

Comment: I see. I figured I'd have to do something like this. I'd tried `camera()` before, but apparently didn't read all the way through documentation. Thanks again.